# Including references from supplementary material in the reference section of the main text

Tags: bibliographies, journal-publishing, journal

I am preparing a manuscript for submission to *Science*, the guidelines state that authors may submit supplementary materials for posting on the Science Web site, however I am unable to format the references correctly. The guidelines state:

> References only cited in the supplementary materials should be include at the end of the reference section of the main text, and the reference numbering should continue as if the Supplementary Materials was a continuation of the main text.

I currently have a `main.tex` file and a `supplementary.tex` file, each containing several citations. If I understand the guidelines correctly, when compiled I need the references in `supplementary.pdf` to continue where the numbering for the main file finished and be included in the main bibliography.

Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want achieve. You are asking how to get the references cited in the main text, without actually citing them? Or how to start numbering in the Suppl. where it ended in the main text? Or both? It would be best to post a minimal working example, showing what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I think both. If I read the guidelines correctly, then anything referenced in 'supplementary.tex' should appear in the bibliography of 'main.pdf'. The numbering of references should continue as if these were in 'main.tex'. 'supplementary.pdf' should not contain a bibliography but the references should be numbered as in 'main.pdf'.

I don't currently have much of a working example as I have no idea how to do this. I just have two tex files that each contain references.

Comment: This is exactly what a working minmal example is. Two .tex files, reduced to the bare minimum to reproduce what you want. For instance, we do not know with what system you are creating the reference list (BibTeX or BibLaTeX; with natbib or not, etc.). Answers will differ in dependence of this information. So again, please post a working minimal example! As for the first part, however: `\nocite{Ref}` adds a citation to the references without citing it. Adding this for all references in the suppl. immediately before your bibliography should get them into the main text.

Answer (score 4):

Similar guidelines come from PRL journal

> Please format any references copied to the Letter using the following 
>   example:
>
> [20] See Supplemental Material [url], which includes Refs. [21-24].
>
> [21] [first reference in Supplemental Material not already in Letter]
>
> ...
>
> [24] [last reference in Supplemental Material not already in Letter]

This is my solution to this problem:

1. In the main TEX file include all the references using `\nocite{key}`.
2. Generate the PDF and BBL file.
3. Modify the BBL file to meet the order and style requirements.
4. Comment out `\bibliography{bib_library}`
5. Include the modified BBL file in the main TEX and supplementary TEX files using `\input{modified_bibliography.bbl}`

Answer (score 0):

1. You parse your supplementary file e.g., perl -e '$x=`cat $ARGV[0]`;while($x=~/\cite{(.*?)}/g){print "\nocite{$1}\n"}' supp.tex > nocite.tex
2. include nocite.tex in your main.tex using \input{nocite.tex} before the bibliography, compile it, and run bibtex to generate main.bbl
3. Include main.bbl into your supplementary \input{main.bbl}, compile twice to get the labels, then remove \input{main.bbl} and compile once again. The references will remain, but the bibliography wont be printed